# mediawiki markup: not to break numbering in multilevel lists

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

Is there a way not to break numbering in multilevel lists?

our management people want this

```
 # item 1
 # item 2
 ## subitem 2.1
 ## subitem 2.2
 # item 3
```

to be displayed as

```
1. item 1
2. item 2
   2.1 item 2.1
   2.2 item 2.2
3. item 3
```

Comment: For me subitem 2.1 is correctly numbered as 1., isn't that what you want? If not, could you explain what exactly do you want?

Comment: I want `##item 2.1` to display as `2.1 item 2.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a mediawiki issue: MW does not output the numbers, but just ordered list tags (html: `<ol>`). The numbering happens in your browser according to the CSS rules for `ol` elements.

It might be possible to change this behavior with some tricky CSS, using counters and content-insertion.